# Programmatic create timebased trigger for spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm not able to find this in the documentation, but is it possible to programmatically create time based trigger for another spreadsheet?

Comment: Dealing with the exact same thing. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_triggers_programmatically

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear, I mean create a timebased trigger for another spreadsheet. I want something like the event trigger, you can use this .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet), is it possible?

Comment: As a time-based trigger is triggered by, well, time, as opposed to a spreadsheet event, I'm not sure it would make sense to have a forSpreadsheet() method. Of course, the function to which you are applying the time-based trigger can operate on a specific spreadsheet... is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes.  I created a template spreadsheet which has the custom function and a time-based trigger calling this custom function. But when I make a copy of this template, I lost the trigger, so I'm trying to create the trigger again and attach it to the new spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Dealing with the exact same thing. @louis did you find a solution for this?