# When copy a spreadsheet, trigger not get copy

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a spreadsheet with the Scripts and timebased trigger in it, when I use DocsList to make a copy, the trigger is not get copy, is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: This is the same question that you just posted here ... at least answer is the same!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatic create timebased trigger for spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843078/programmatic-create-timebased-trigger-for-spreadsheet)